# Mongo query for an array is a subarray

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm looking for a query that acts as `$setIsSubset`, except accounting for duplicate values.

For example, `[1,1,2,3]` is a subset of `[1,2,3,4]`, because sets don't have duplicate values.

How can I write a query such that `[1,1,2,3]` is not a subset of `[1,2,3,4]`?

An example of expected outputs:

```
INPUT     |  TARGET  | RESULT
[1]        [1,2,3,4]   TRUE
[1,2,3]    [1,2,3,4]   TRUE
[1,1,2,3]  [1,2,3,4]   FALSE
[1,2,3,4]  [1,2,3,4]   TRUE
[1,3]      [1,2,3,4]   TRUE
[1,11,5]   [1,2,3,4]   FALSE
[1,2,2,3]  [1,2,3,4]   FALSE
```

Comment: Clarification: you say "For example, [1,1,2,3] is a subset of [1,2,3,4]" but then have that result as false in your table. Which one of those is incorrect?

Comment: It is a subset. It is not a sub-array. I want to find sub-arrays. So the result of false is that it is not a sub-array.  @Steve

Comment: Why not just use $sum and when dups return false, since the set operations ignore dups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would suggest not to do such heavy processing in mongo** query as you can do the same task easily in any programming language. But, if you still need it in mongo, the following query can get you the expected output, provided both input and target arrays are sorted.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            "modifiedInput":{
                $reduce:{
                    "input":"$input",
                    "initialValue":{
                        "data":[],
                        "postfix":0,
                        "index":0,
                        "nextElem":{
                            $arrayElemAt:["$input",1]
                        }
                    },
                    "in":{
                        "data":{
                            $concatArrays:[
                                "$$value.data",
                                [
                                    {
                                        $concat:[
                                            {
                                                $toString:"$$this"
                                            },
                                            "-",
                                            {
                                                $toString:"$$value.postfix"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "postfix":{
                            $cond:[
                                {
                                    $eq:["$$this","$$value.nextElem"]
                                },
                                {
                                    $sum:["$$value.postfix",1]
                                },
                                0
                            ]
                        },
                        "nextElem": {
                            $arrayElemAt:["$input", { $sum : [ "$$value.index", 2] }]
                        },
                        "index":{
                            $sum:["$$value.index",1]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "modifiedTarget":{
                $reduce:{
                    "input":"$target",
                    "initialValue":{
                        "data":[],
                        "postfix":0,
                        "index":0,
                        "nextElem":{
                            $arrayElemAt:["$target",1]
                        }
                    },
                    "in":{
                        "data":{
                            $concatArrays:[
                                "$$value.data",
                                [
                                    {
                                        $concat:[
                                            {
                                                $toString:"$$this"
                                            },
                                            "-",
                                            {
                                                $toString:"$$value.postfix"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "postfix":{
                            $cond:[
                                {
                                    $eq:["$$this","$$value.nextElem"]
                                },
                                {
                                    $sum:["$$value.postfix",1]
                                },
                                0
                            ]
                        },
                        "nextElem": {
                            $arrayElemAt:["$target", { $sum : [ "$$value.index", 2] }]
                        },
                        "index":{
                            $sum:["$$value.index",1]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "matched":{
                $eq:[
                    {
                        $size:{
                            $setDifference:["$modifiedInput.data","$modifiedTarget.data"]
                        }
                    },
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6e005db674d5c90f46d355"),
    "input" : [
        1
    ],
    "target" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6e005db674d5c90f46d356"),
    "input" : [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "target" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6e005db674d5c90f46d357"),
    "input" : [
        1,
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "target" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6e005db674d5c90f46d358"),
    "input" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ],
    "target" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6e005db674d5c90f46d359"),
    "input" : [
        1,
        3
    ],
    "target" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6e005db674d5c90f46d35a"),
    "input" : [
        1,
        5,
        11
    ],
    "target" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6e005db674d5c90f46d35b"),
    "input" : [
        1,
        2,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "target" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "matched" : true }
{ "matched" : true }
{ "matched" : false }
{ "matched" : true }
{ "matched" : true }
{ "matched" : false }
{ "matched" : false }
```

**Explanation:** To avoid elimination of same values, we are adding the postfix counter to each. For example, [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4] would become ["1-0","1-1","1-2","2-0","3-0","3-1","4-0","4-1","4-2"]. Afrer the conversion of both input and target arrays, the set difference is calculated. It's a match, if the size of set difference is zero.

Comment: This is crazy. I'm not tied to doing it in mongo, I just didn't think it would be difficult! Kudos to you for figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation:

```
let input = [1,2,3];
let inputSize = 3;

db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            uniqueTarget: { $setUnion: [ "$target" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            filtered: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: input,
                    initialValue: "$uniqueTarget",
                    in: { 
                        $filter: { 
                            input: "$$value", 
                            as: "current", 
                            cond: { $ne: [ "$$this", "$$current" ] } 
                        } 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            result: { 
                $eq: [ 
                    { $size: "$filtered" }, 
                    { $subtract: [ { $size: "$uniqueTarget" }, inputSize ] } 
                ] 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

It starts with [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) to ensure there are no duplicates in `target` array. Then you can run [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to iterate through `input` and remove currently processed element from target. Every iteration should remove single element so expected [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) of `filtered` is equal [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) of `uniqueTarget` - `inputSize`

[Mongo Playground (1)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0QGvjDVtr8r)

[Mongo Playground (2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0OSi3E5KMeo)

Comment: It's showing ```false``` for ```"input":[1,1,1]``` and ```"target":[1,1,1,1]```